# How to get the DataGridTextColumn sender's datagrid parent

Tags: wpf, datagrid, parent

Hi I have a datagrid and the DataGridTextColumn shown in code below:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="" Width="1*" Binding="{Binding FORECAST_MIN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" >
 <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <EventSetter Event="LostFocus" Handler="fMin_LostFocus" />                  
    </Style>
</DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```

Now in the LostFocus event, I'd like to get the parent datagrid from the sender.  Code

```
private void fMin_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
//Get the datagrid parent
}
```

Is there a easy way to do so?  Thank you. Something like adding a Tag?

#

Both Jeff and OptimusPrime's answers work.  It only allows me to choose one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff's answer should work.
Since you mentioned "Tag". This might be another way to go? Probably not the most elegant way though.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>    
            <TextBox Text="{Binding FORECAST_MIN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" LostFocus="fMin_LostFocus"/>    
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

and in your code:

```
private void fMin_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)sender;
        DataGrid parentDataGrid = (DataGrid)tb.Tag;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to traverse the visual tree until you find the proper parent.

```
DependencyObject depObj = sender as DependencyObject;
while (depObj != null && !(depObj is DataGrid)) {
    depObj = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent (depObj);
}
DataGrid dg = (DataGrid) depObj;
```